# Type signature of runErrorT

Tags: haskell

I have a function, target say, which demands a parameter of type

```
target :: Action m UserId -> something
```

where m is any monad.

I acquire the parameter from an existing function, call it "func"

```
func :: something -> Action m UserId
```

to which I wish to retrofit an ErrorT transformer

```
func :: something -> ErrorT String (Action m) UserId
```

When I use runErrorT on func in order to extract the successful/failed result, I of course get a result of type

```
Action m (Either String UserId)
```

I.e. the either representing success or failure is embedded in the surrounding monad. This is great for some purposes e.g. testing for left and right in the context of the Action monad.

What I really need is a version of runErrorT which returns
    Either String (Action m UserId)

because then I could just take the Right value and use it. What do I do in these circumstances? Alternatively is there a clever way of rejigging

```
Action m (Either String UserId) -> Either String (Action m UserId)
```

but where I don't have access to the necessary constructor

```
UserId -> Action m UserId
```

since it so happens that Action is itself a transformer

```
type Action = ReaderT MongoDBContext
```

Comment: Sounds like you actually want `Action (ErrorT m String) UserId` and then some sort of function `runAction :: Action m a -> m (Action Identity a)`.  (More standard names would be `ActionT` for what you call `Action` and `Action` for what you call `ActionT Identity`).

Comment: What do you mean "the necessary constructor `UserId -> Action m UserId`".  That's just `return` and I don't see how it would help.

Comment: Yes, @Tom. It is relevant that Action is a synonym for a transformer `type Action m = ReaderT MongoDBContext m`. So I will try to turn the problem inside out and see where I get to.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have

```
func :: a -> ErrorT String (Action m) UserId
target :: Action m UserId -> b
```

Then

```
run :: a -> Action m (Either String b)
run a = do
  result <- runErrorT $ func a
  return $ case result of
    Left  str -> Left str
    Right uid -> Right $ target (return uid)
```

Or more succinctly

```
run = runErrorT . fmap (target . return) . func
```

Comment: That seems to be the opposite of what Robert asked for.  He wants to get something of type `Either String (Action m UserId)`.

Comment: True, but, barring further knowledge of the `Action` monad, he can't get that from what he has.

Comment: Agreed, hence why I think he should use `Action` as a transformer.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this can't be done without knowledge of the specific `m`.  For example, this is no function of type `IO (Either String Int) -> Either String (IO Int)` that doesn't use `unsafePerformIO` or something like that.

You *can* write something like:

```
dupNoEx :: IO (Either String Int) -> IO (Either String (IO Int))
dupNoEx act = do
    ev <- act
    case v of
     Left  s -> return $ Left s
     Right i -> return . Right $ return i
```

but, I don't know how valuable it might be.